# Does shadow variable help optaplanner to make a better initial solution?

Tags: optaplanner

I’m using Optaplanner to make a schedule and it works quite good.

After reading the documentation I have realised that I should use at least 1 (or more) shadow variables since my drool-file is calling methods that does a lot of calculations based on the value of the planningVariable.

I spent a couple of hours rewriting my code to have a shadow variable, but then I notice that the initial solution was really bad (compared to not having shadow variables) and I had to wait severals of minutes just to get an OK result. Is this normal? It did not look like the initial solution used the shadow variable at all.

Answer (score 3):

The question is very generic, and so my answer will be, too.

Sometimes you can simplify the problem by introducing shadow variables or other forms of caching. If you find the right balance, you can indeed speed up the Drools calculation and - as a result - get to the same solution in a shorter amount of time. And therefore, reach better solutions in the same amount of time.

That said, introducing shadow variables shouldn't really change your scores - only how quickly they're calculated. If you're seeing different scores for the same `@PlanningSolution`, you have in fact changed your problem and the relative performance is no longer comparable.

Also, you may want to check out [environment modes](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#environmentMode) to make sure you haven't inadvertently introduced score corruptions into your problem.